# How to add variable from PHP into a form using a button with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have these two codes that I want to combine into one, so when I click the `genbtn` it will add the response from the PHP file into the 'wallet' form like the function below adds the text 'bitcoin wallet after click' to it.

Instead of displaying it in an alert box like it does now, the variable in the PHP file that I want to display is `$public` if that helps.

I've been sitting fiddling with the code for 3 hours now with no luck.
You can check how it works now on for better understanding.

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $('#genbtn').one('click', function () {

    var text = $('#wallet');
    text.val(text.val() + ' bitcoin wallet after click');

  });
});
</script>
```

and:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'addygen.php',
  success: function (response) {
    alert(response);
  }
});
</script>
```

html:

```
 <input type="text" id="wallet" maxlength="34" pattern="^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$" 
            placeholder="Your Bitcoin wallet's address"></input>
```

Comment: Could you please simplify your question? I am not exactly getting what you are asking.

Comment: I'll try, I want the string displayed in addygen.php to be displayed in the 'wallet' form when you click the 'genbtn'.

Comment: You have to show what is `#wallet`. Post your HTML.

Comment: Just posted it.

Comment: the output of `addygen.php` is `1KiJnydDYR9ZHfxNWrfGUtUKDJgVkTo4Qm` (string like this)... That doesn't look like what you wish to be displayed.

Comment: That is exactly what I wish to display. Look at the pattern for the wallet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here where we are:

1. When I used the following code with a local `phpPage.php`, it works fine
2. When I put the `url: 'http://www.ubit.ca/addygen.php'` the **developer tool** showed me the following error:

> the connexion used to get resources not encrypted

So I think that he problem is whith your permission to acces to the `http://www.ubit.ca/addygen.php` file.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.ubit.ca/addygen.php',
    ifModified: true,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data){
        $("#wallet")
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="wallet" maxlength="34" pattern="^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$" placeholder="Your Bitcoin wallet's address"/>
```

Comment: I've tried it before and it doesn't work, I just need the response added to the form. So I removed the "+ ' bitcoin wallet after click'" and its still doesnt work.

Comment: @NipBoss which form ? please can you add you **HTML** code ?! I need to know where you exactely want to put this response

Comment: Ok, one moment.

Comment: @NipBoss I edited my answer, try my solution on your local machine & see if the code is working, for me it works very fine. GOOD LUCK

Comment: Thank you very much, you basically had it. I just modified it a bit.

Comment: @NipBoss glad it helps ^^

Answer (score 0):

here's a code snippet of the solution:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#genbtn').one('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'addygen.php',
            success: function(response) {
                var text = $('#wallet');
                text.val(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```