# how to get the value from php with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to get the 2 values separately in order to fill automatically the input in the first file from the PHP via AJAX, but when i console.log(data) I get all the data and I want to retrieve it separately in order to put it in different tags

```
<input id="regist" type="text" name="regist" onblur="passdata();">
<input id="atyp" type="text" name="atyp" >
<input id="mtow" type="text" name="mtow" >

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){})

function passdata() {
    var regist = $('#regist').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'checkdb.php',
        data: 'regist='+regist,
        success: function(data){
            var atyp = $('#myvalue1').val();
            var mtow = $('#myvalue1').val();
            $('#atyp').text(atyp);
            $('#mtow').text(mtow);
            alert (aty+mtow);
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

and PHP file.... of course with db connection

```
$regist = $_POST['regist'];

$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pwd,$db);
$sql= ("SELECT * FROM aircrafts where regist='$regist'");
$datas = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

foreach ($datas as $row) {};

if(mysqli_num_rows($datas) == 0) {
    echo 'non ce niente';
} else { ?>

    <span id="myvalue1"><?php echo $atyp =  $row['atyp'];?></span>
    <span id="myvalue2"><?php echo $atyp =  $row['mtow'];?></span>

<?php };

?>
```

Comment: I invite you to check my answer here: [How to add variable from PHP into a form using a button with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393845/how-to-add-variable-from-php-into-a-form-using-a-button-with-jquery/46394057#46394057)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: As to your question...currently your PHP script returns a single HTML string. If you want to retrieve the output values separately, and insert them into existing markup, format the output as JSON instead.

Comment: You can also have a look on this answer, which should explain exactly what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900223/passing-a-php-variable-to-ajax/45900326#45900326

Comment: Are you aware that `$(document).ready(function(){})` is useless the way you implemented it. Maybe its just due to abstraction for the post but if not you should nest all the code into the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Ajax request to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'checkdb.php',
    data: 'regist='+regist,
    dataType: 'json', // NEW LINE
    success: function(data) {
        //var atyp = $('#myvalue1').val();
        //var mtow = $('#myvalue1').val();
        //$('#atyp').text(atyp);
        //$('#mtow').text(mtow);
        var atyp = data.atyp;
        var mtow = data.mtow;
        alert ('aty: ' + aty , 'mtow: ' + mtow);
        console.log(data);
    }
})
```

and in your PHP: change these lines

```
else{?>
<span id="myvalue1"><?php echo $atyp =  $row['atyp'];?></span>
<span id="myvalue2"><?php echo $atyp =  $row['mtow'];?></span>
<?php };
```

to this exactly lines

```
else {
    echo json_encode( $row );
}
```

---

*EDIT*

**Regarding your "DOM-event"-handling ("document onready" and "input#regist onblur") I recommend to do it like this.**

HTML:

```
<!-- <input id="regist" type="text" name="regist" onblur="passdata();"> -->
<input id="regist" type="text" name="regist">
<input id="atyp" type="text" name="atyp">
<input id="mtow" type="text" name="mtow">
```

JavaScript:

```
function passdata(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'checkdb.php',
        data: 'regist=' + $(event.target).val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // on blur event
    $('#regist').on('blur', passdata)
    // on input event | maybe this would be also an interesting option as it fires immidiately on input
    // $('#regist').on('input', passdata)
})
```

*This bootstrap seperates the logic from the markup which is a good practice in general.*

Comment: I m sorry it doesnt work . alert is showing only aty:

Comment: <span id="myvalue1">C525</span>
      <span id="myvalue2">3500</span> this is the console.log

Comment: is an empty log

Comment: @scunja Please take a look again at my updated answer. Now it should work like a charme. If not, feel free to leave another comment...

Comment: {"id":"1","regist":"GPAOL","atyp":"C525","mtow":"3500"} now the log is displaying this. but if I alert (atyp) is giving me 'undefined'

Comment: It was a typo error from my side.... Now is working like a charm!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: My apologies !!

Comment: @scunja You are welcome - appreciate to help. I stringly recommend to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900223/passing-a-php-variable-to-ajax/45900326#45900326) to really understand what is going on...!